# SQL AVG() Returning the wrong result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a function and a stored procedure that used this function, when i run the function seratelty with the stored procedure i get the correct result but when i use this function with the stored procedure i get wrong result. here is my function and stored procedure

**Function**

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME='2018-01-01',
@ZoneIds VARCHAR(1000) = '225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,240,242,244'

SELECT  AVG(c.Value)
        FROM
        (
            SELECT  SUM(SurfaceTotale) AS Value,
                    carac.Date
            FROM fait.CaracGeoMois carac 
            WHERE carac.Date BETWEEN @Date AND  DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@Date),12,31)
            AND carac.IdGeographie IN (SELECT 30000000  + value  FROM STRING_SPLIT(@ZoneIds, ','))  
            GROUP BY carac.Date         
        ) C
    GROUP BY YEAR(C.Date)
```

**Stored procedure**

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME ='2018-01-01',
        @EndDate DATETIME='2018-31-12'

SELECT c.FluidId,
   c.Year,
   SUM(ConsoKW) AS Consumption,
   sproc.GetCarac(STRING_AGG(CAST(c.GeographyId AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ','), DATEFROMPARTS(c.Year, 1, 1), 1, 1) AS Characteristic
FROM fait.ConsumptionDaily AS c
WHERE  c.GeographyId IN (225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,240,242,244)
AND c.PerimeterItemDomainId = 2
AND DATEFROMPARTS(c.Year, c.Month, c.Day) >= @StartDate
AND DATEFROMPARTS(c.Year, c.Month, c.Day) <= @EndDate
GROUP BY c.FluidId,
     c.Year
```

The result is the same between SP and function when the number of geographie ids is limited to 9 `GeographyId`

```
c.GeographyId IN (225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233)
```

after 9 geographie ids the resulat of SP doesn't change, it always show 13689 as result.

Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging the function using :

```
DECLARE @EXECUTION_STRING2 VARCHAR(1000) ='echo '+@ZoneIds +' >> 
C:\Users\Public\debuginfo.txt'
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @EXECUTION_STRING2
```

The probleme come from the type of @ZonesIds, after changing the type from `VARCHAR(1000)` to `NVARCHAR(max)` everything work as expected.